# How does it make query ndb.AND condition more smart

Tags: arrays, google-app-engine, python-2.7, iteration, app-engine-ndb

I try to make query for tag search.
tags: how many tags  ex.3
q: array of tags  ex.['foo','hoo','poo']

```
def queryByTags(cls, tags, q):

        def one():
            qry = models.Card.query(models.Card.tags_value == q[0])
            return qry

        def two():
            qry = models.Card.query(ndb.AND(models.Card.tags_value == q[0],
                                                models.Card.tags_value == q[1]))
            return qry

        def three():
            qry = models.Card.query(ndb.AND(models.Card.tags_value == q[0],
                                                models.Card.tags_value == q[1],
                                                models.Card.tags_value == q[2]))
            return qry

        tags_len = {1: one,
                    2: two,
                    3: three,
                    }

        return tags_len[tags]()
```

This method can use up to 3 tags.  I can copy code myself and extend it until 7,8,9...
It is very sad way...
Is there any smart way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pseudo python-ndb (I didn't run my code but you'll get it) I would say that a way would be to do:

```
cards_count = Card.query().filter(tags_value==q[0])\
  .filter(tags_value==q[1])\
  .filter(tags_value==q[2]).count()
```

or if iterating dynamic array (unknown length)

```
cards_count = Card.query()
for value in q:
  q = q.filter(tags_value==value)
cards_count = q.count()
```

Comment: qry = web_models.Card.query()   
for value in q:   
   qry  = qry.filter(web_models.Card.tags_value == value)
Was perfect.  Thank you very much for quick respond and answer